# Is it possible to add a branch to existing fireplace blower?

Tags: heating, garage, fireplace

My fireplace has two blowers behind grates in the brick. Fans behind these lower grates mix air with heated air from behind the firebox and kick out a serious amount of heat into the room. The heated air is forced out of the upper grates on each side of the fireplace.

I have created a golf simulator in my garage and am looking at heating options. Is having a mason create another tunnel/branch terminating in the garage, though the cinder block possible? The garage is located immediately behind the fireplace.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the skill of the mason, local building codes, the configuration of the fireplace ducts and the cost I'm sure a new duct is feasible.

What you may want to consider is it worth the price and disruption to the household. Also would it make more economical sense to have a separate heating unit for the garage?

A gas fired ceiling hung 50000 BTU furnace can be purchased new for under $500. It might be worth it depending on the cost for the mason th reroute the fireplace duct.

Comment: No gas in the house; electric only. I've just realized that the duct may be against fire code, being a hole connecting the interior to the garage. Plus it would turn into a heat loss. I just want to take the edge off. I may try an oil filter radiant heater.

Comment: It was worth serious consideration anyway! Any furnace ducts that can be split-off? No violations in doing that.

Comment: With a heat pump, I think that would probably be a lost cost.  Worse case scenario, I could use a ceiling mounted infrared heater just to heat each player between shots, but it would be nice if a radiant heater could bring the garage up to about 50/55 F.

Comment: Maybe this:  http://www.amazon.com/Optimus-H-9010-Garage-Ceiling-Utility/dp/B0041G69CM/ref=sr_1_13?ie=UTF8&qid=1451838971&sr=8-13&keywords=infrared+heaters  . or http://www.amazon.com/Vogelzang-BX22EL-Sweetie-Cast-Stove/dp/B002OMGYHA/ref=sr_1_15?ie=UTF8&qid=1451839160&sr=8-15&keywords=wood+stoves  . Radiant kerosene heater keeps my shop warm, but needs an open air source,